# No migrations are pending using Typeorm CLI and NestJS

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

The issue I'm facing is with running migrations using @nestjs/typeorm ^9.0.1 and typeorm ^0.3.12. Despite being able to build the project and create migrations, when I try to run them, typeorm can't find the migration files (*No migrations are pending*).
I have noticed that the version 0.3.x of typeorm requires Datasource object and that in the version 9.x of @nestjs/typeorm, TypeOrmModuleOptions does not have the cli : {migrationsDir : string} attribute.

Here's a [link](https://github.com/charlescol/basic_repository_typeorm_cli) to the project that reproduces the problem, and an example directory structure :

1. *src\configs\database\dataSource.config.ts*
2. *src\configs\database\postgres.config.ts*
3. *src\configs\database\migrations\1676252827402-Chat.ts*

**postgres.config.ts**

```js
import { DataSourceOptions } from "typeorm";
import { join } from "path";
import { config } from "dotenv";
import CustomNamingStrategy from "./customNamingStrategy";
import { registerAs } from "@nestjs/config";
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from "@nestjs/typeorm";

config();

export const databaseConfig: DataSourceOptions = {
  name: "default",
  type: "postgres",
  url: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl:
    process.env.DATABASE_ENABLE_SSL === "true"
      ? {
          rejectUnauthorized: false,
        }
      : false,
  logging: process.env.DATABASE_ENABLE_LOGGING === "true",
  entities: [join(__dirname, "../../models/*/", "*.entity.{ts,js}")],
  migrations: [join(__dirname, "migrations/*.{ts,js}")],
  synchronize: false,
  migrationsRun: false,
  namingStrategy: new CustomNamingStrategy(),
};

export default registerAs(
  "database",
  () =>
    ({
      ...databaseConfig,
      keepConnectionAlive: true,
    } as TypeOrmModuleOptions)
);
```

**dataSource.config.ts**

```js
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";
import { databaseConfig } from "./postgres.config";

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource(databaseConfig);
```

**package.json**

```js
"typeorm": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli"
"migration:create": "yarn run typeorm migration:create"
"migration:run": "yarn run typeorm migration:run -d src/configs/database/dataSource.config.ts"
```

Although I can use the `create` command successfully, when I use the `run` command, it only displays the message "*No migrations are pending*". I attempted to resolve the issue by changing migrations path to the `DataSourceOptions.migrations` list, but it did not work. I also tried replacing the cli parameter **datasource** with the **dist datasource**, as well as adjusting the migration paths, but these changes did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing a similar issue using the same version of typeorm (^0.3.12), so there might be a bug in this version.

It seems that the migrations are not found anymore if the DataSourceOptions.migrations property is set with the path to the migrations folder.

The ^0.3.12 version seems to be working fine only if the migration classes are directly referenced in DataSourceOptions.migrations, similar to the following:

```
import { Chat1676252827402 } from './migrations/1676252827402-Chat.ts';

export const databaseConfig: DataSourceOptions = {
  ...
  migrations: [Chat1676252827402],
  ...
};
```

Comment: This thread on the typeorm github confirms a bug in 0.3.12. https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/9766

I downgraded with `npm install -s typeorm@0.3.11` and it works now